# Spring Boot YARN doesn't run on Hadoop 2.8.0 client cannot access DataNode

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-boot, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run Spring Boot YARN sample (https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic/ on Windows). In `application.yml` I changed `fsUri` and `resourceManagerHost` to point to my VM's host `192.168...`.
But when I'm trying to run application Exceprion appears:

```
DFSClient: Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1508)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1284)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1237)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:449)
[2017-05-27 19:59:49.570] boot - 7728  INFO [Thread-5] --- DFSClient: Abandoning BP-646365587-10.0.2.15-1495898351938:blk_1073741830_1006
[2017-05-27 19:59:49.602] boot - 7728  INFO [Thread-5] --- DFSClient: Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.0.2.15:50010,DS-f909ec7a-8374-4cdd-9cfc-0e778810d98c,DISK]
[2017-05-27 19:59:49.647] boot - 7728  WARN [Thread-5] --- DFSClient: DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /app/gs-yarn-basic/gs-yarn-basic-container-0.1.0.jar could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
```

It means that DataNode isn't accessible from my host machine. For that reason I added to hdfs-site.xml

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
  <value>true</value>
  <description>Whether clients should use datanode hostnames when
    connecting to datanodes.
  </description>
</property>
```

But it still throws that exception.

I've got Hadoop 2.8.0 running on my VM. Here's conf. files:

core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
       <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000</value>
   </property>

</configuration>
```

hdfs-site.xml

```
    <configuration>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.replication</name>
           <value>1</value>
       </property>
       <property>
           <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
           <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.0/data/namenode</value>
       </property>

       <property>
           <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
           <value>/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.0/data/datanode</value>
       </property>

        <property>
            <name>dfs.permissions.enabled</name>
            <value>false</value>
        </property>

        <property>
           <name>dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname</name>
           <value>true</value>
           <description>Whether clients should use datanode hostnames when
              connecting to datanodes.
           </description>
        </property>
   </configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>    
   <property>
       <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
       <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
<configuration>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
       <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
    <property>
       <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
       <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
        <value>8192</value>
    </property>
        <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
        <value>8192</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-
           disk-percentage</name>
        <value>99</value>
    </property>    
</configuration>
```

Comment: Why did you put `0.0.0.0:9000` in `core-site.xml? That should either be IP or hostname.

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, it works after changed to IP, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `core-site.xml` should point to `Namenode` address but currently its pointing to `0.0.0.0` which means all addresses on the local machine. This will create ambiguous result as each machine shall be treated as `Namenode`.

`Namenode` should be only one in a hadoop cluster.

Replacing the `0.0.0.0` with the `Namenode`'s `ip` or `hostname` should resolve the issue you are facing.

Comment: Do you think it shouldn't be deleted?

Comment: That's not so bad

Answer (score 1):

Spring connected to YARN after changed 0.0.0.0:9000 to [VM's IP]:9000 in core-site.xml. Thanks to @RameshMaharjan

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, Ohhh, I'm sorry:) Thank you!

Comment: @RameshMaharjan, sure:)