# Spring Boot YARN how to deploy to Hadoop

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, spring-boot, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to run Spring Boot YARN sample (https://spring.io/guides/gs/yarn-basic/ on Windows). But example uses local hadoop. In application.yml I changed fsUri and resourceManagerHost to point to my VM's host 192.168....

But it doesn't work. 
When I'm moving jars to VM and run - it works. But I want to run from my host machine against another node (in my case VM).

And there is a question: what is the right way to run my app against another, real Hadoop YARN, not against local?

I've searched, read, watched a lot of info, but there were no definitive explanation about deploying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial link provided in the question is for `single node cluster` where `Namenode`, `Resourcemanager`, `ApplicationManager`, `datanode`, `Nodemanager` and all other `YARN nodes` run on the same local machine. The address `localhost:8020` works in such case.

But as you mention that the intention is to make a `cluster`, you will have to make sure there is only one `namenode` and `resourcemanager`.

If you define `localhost` in the `configuration files` then every nodes in the `cluster` will act `namenode` and `resourcemanager` and `hadoop` will get confused about reporting and updates queries. Thus resulting to ambiguous situation.

The solution is to define only one `namenode` and `resourcemanager` and this can be done by specifying an `IP` or `hostname` of the `namenode (master)` in the configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

Just needed right configuration of Hadoop, in my case it fixed in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44219690/spring-boot-yarn-doesnt-run-on-hadoop-2-8-0-client-cannot-access-datanode) post.

Comment: Shall I answer this one as well ;) hehe

Comment: Answer to this question too, please:) @RameshMaharjan